# Grails deployment data issue

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment

I have created a grails application which utilizes highcharts and D3 js libraries. The data source for these charts is currently MySQL server, which is running on my PC

When the app is run on my PC in development mode using the 'grails run-app',it runs perfectly well. 
Now, I want to deploy the application(production mode) and have created a war file using "grails war" and am using "Apache tomcat 7.0.54" as my container but it throws up many errors when I open my app inside the manager mode of tomcat server.
Also, the visualization is not coming up properly - only one dropdown(instead of 4) and no graphs are coming

This is the error that is observed when clicking on the filters:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/marchmock2/Tablev1class/salesjson 404 (Not Found) d3.v3.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u (index):409
```

It is not able to read the json files that are needed for the visualization at all. 
I think that the main problem lies in the Datasource.groovy. 
Code for that:
Dev mode (working) :

```
development {
        dataSource {

            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/marchmock2?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            username = "root"
            password = "root"
        }
```

Production mode(WAR file)
Not working :

Code:

```
production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/marchmock2?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            username = "root"
            password = "root"
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=false
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
               jdbcInterceptors="ConnectionState"
            }
        }
    }
```

So, the problem could be

- Erroneous codes in Datasource.groovy
- Apache Tomcat cannot find the mysql db and hence cannot get the relevant data

Also, how exactly is the servlet container pulling the data from the database? I fail to understand this as I am very new in Tomcat and Grails

Any suggestions/approaches to solve this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/marchmock2/Tablev1class/salesjson` - This controller name seems odd - Tablev1class.

Comment: How does the grails controller action look like that is referenced and servesthe json structure?

Comment: How you create link in the .gsp(view) that use your js?

Comment: Do you see any errors/exceptions in the application/Tomcat log files?

Comment: Can you give us more information about your controller and action? I don't think it has to do with your database at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a Ajax call to http://yourdomain.com:8080/marchmock2/Tablev1class/salesjson ?

So in the url there are three important thing:

1. marchmock2: base application name
2. Tablev1class: name of controller
3. salesjson: name of action

When you create the war you rename it to marchmock2.war? If the name of war is different for example marchmock2-0.1.war the right url will come:

```
http://yourdomain.com:8080/marchmock2-0.1/Tablev1class/salesjson
```

So when you put a link in your javascript make attention and use the grails tag library, g.createLink for controller and action and g.createLinkTo for resources.

Hope i help,
regards.